# Failure/Error: @user = User.create!(@attr)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am following railstutorial.org on Chapter 7 and when running tests I get the error

User password encryption has_password? method should be true if the passwords match
     Failure/Error: @user = User.create!(@attr)
     undefined method `password' for #<User:0xa242d18>
     # ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:105:in`block (3 levels) in '

line 105 of user_spec.rb:105 is    @u   @user = User.create!(@attr)ser = User.create!(@attr)

Answer (score 0):

Is your database updated? The users table should have a column 'password,' did you forget to run a migration?